# Trying to stack values with PHP

Tags: php, oop

Im currently trying to make a little dice game in php. Right now Im trying to make a "currentscore" where all the points from a rand(1,6) are stacked into a single variable.

Here is the class Im doing this in:

```
    <?php
class CDice {

   public $roll;
   public $currentscore;

   public function Roll()
   {
       $this->roll = rand(1,6);

       return $this->roll;
   }

   public function currentScore()
   {
       $this->currentscore += $this->roll;

       return $this->currentscore;
   }
}
```

I don't under stand why `$this->currentscore += $this->roll;` doesn't work.

Comment: Initialize `$this->currentscore` with 0 first.

Comment: It works fine. Try this: `$dice = new CDice();
for ( $i=0; $i<3; $i++)
        echo "Rolled ", $dice->Roll(), " score: ", $dice->currentScore(), "<br/>\n";` If I were you though, I'd update `currentScore` in `Roll()`; calling `currentScore()` multiple times will keep adding the last roll.

Comment: $this->currentscore = 0; did not work :(
Maybe I was unclear, my objective is saving the score from each roll in the same round to "currentscore". Later when the round is over the score from "currentscore" will be moved to "totalscore".

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Show us more code and say what exactly isn't working.

Comment: When I say "not working" I mean that "currentscore" doesnt add up and only shows the same value as the current roll.

Comment: Give us an [MCVE] to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, Didn't relize I had to use sessions to store data over page refreshes. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do realise that at the end of execution of this class no values are kept right? If you wish to transfer over this data to the next page render, you should use PHP sessions.

```
<?php
  class CDice {

   public $roll;
   public $currentscore = 0;

   public function Roll(){
       $this->roll = rand(1,6);
       $this->currentscore += $this->roll;

       return $this->roll;
   }

   public function currentScore(){
     return $this->currentscore;
   }

    public function __construct(){
      if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
        $this->currentscore = isset($_SESSION['dice.score']) ? $_SESSION['dice.score'] ? 0;
        # In PHP 7.0
        # $this->currentscore = $_SESSION['dice.score'] ?? 0;
      } else {
        echo 'session has not been initiated';
      }
    }
  }

  session_start();
  $tmp = new CDice();

  echo $tmp->Roll();
  echo $tmp->Roll();
  echo $tmp->currentScore();

?>
```

Also not assigning an "initalial" value to a variable before trying to add things to it with +=, -=, etc causes PHP to throw a warning.

Comment: I see, that explains alot. I did make this game with spaghetti code and had sessions all over the place. This was suppose to be a clean game :)